# Jar packaging in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I am creating a Spring Boot multi module project.. Module A has a dependency on Module B ..

Module A runs fine when I run in exploded form..

```
          mvn spring-boot:run
```

But I am unable to package the jar along with dependencies 
so that I can execute it as

```
          java -jar Module-A.jar
```

Module A pom.xml is below:

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>Module-Test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.module</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>Module-A</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.NotifyApp</start-class>
    <main.class>com.NotifyApp</main.class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module-B</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project Module-A: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refe
r to an existing file

Parent  pom.xml

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>Module-Test</artifactId>
<groupId>com.module</groupId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>Module-A</module>
    <module>Module-B</module>
    <module>Module-C</module>        
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <artifactId>Module-Parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</parent>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>Module-A</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>Module-B</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>com.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>Module-C</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>starter-service</artifactId>
            <version>${starter.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Which command do you execute and from which location ?

Comment: I am executing mvn clean install parallel inside Module-A directory (parallel to pom.xml)  .. This is done on Intellij idea terminal

Comment: Ok. You may have some issues from the parent pom. Can you show it ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the parent pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use this plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html for maven, which will put all of the dependency jars into target/dependencies when you run

```
mvn clean package
```

Then I copy the jars into a folder (which I usually call lib) and I include lib/* in my classpath. The final run script usually looks like

```
java -cp lib/*: my.package.MySpringBootMain
```

Comment: Awesome .. This helped me to run my jar in both the ways .. But still I am not sure why spring boot maven plugins did not support this  packaging in my case ..  I accept your answer (The one you provided in the link ) as it solved my problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
<executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

It's not needed.

Comment: I removed it .. I get the jar file inside target/Module-A.jar .. but it does not contain the dependent modules packaged within  it .. I short , I need a fat jar for Module-A containing Module-B and its dependencies ..

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency of module B in module A's pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module-B</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Use **maven clean compile package install** command for module B, to build module B first and then run **maven clean compile package** on Module A. This will out Module B into Module A.

There is no module A's reference required in Module B's pom.xml

Comment: Sorry don't run `mvn clean compile package install` that's duplication of many parts. Only simply `mvn clean package` is necessary..and of course using repackaging of spring-boot-maven-plugin...also `mvn clean compile package` is duplicating things just `mvn clean package`..The [life cycle contains `compile`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score -1):

you sure know, but you can initialize your project from this link
[Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/)
, it automatically generates the configuration with what you need